# Deserializing JSON in .NET that I have no control over

Tags: .net, json

I have to deserialize JSON strings that I don't have any control over. This is an extreme example, but it gets the point across:

```
string fooJson = @"
{
    'foo_baz': 123,
    foo_bar: 'buuuu',
    ""Xyz"": ""\/Date(405928800000-0600)\/"" //1982-11-12
}";
```

The JSON has to be deserialized into this C# class that I can't change:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    public int Baz { get; private set; }

    public DateTime Xyz { get; set; }
}
```

Serializing `Foo` is no problem.

After deserializing, the results should be...

- `Bar` == `"buuuu"`
- `Baz` == `123`
- `Xyz` == `DateTime.MinValue` or uninitialized

...but I have problems.

`DataContractJsonSerializer`, along with `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes on `Foo` and its members, is basically perfect, except it balks on JSON properties and strings that aren't properly double-quoted.

`JavaScriptSerializer` seems to handle the non-standard quoting, but I can't get it to ignore `Xyz` or map `foo_baz` to `Baz` and `foo_bar` to `Bar`.

This is going to be part of a distributable class library, so I'm trying to avoid third-party tools—such as JSON.NET—as much as possible. However, if there's no built-in way to do what I need, I'm open to suggestions of third-party tools.

Comment: I hate to point out the obvious but this is the problem: "except it balks on JSON properties and strings that aren't properly double-quoted"....then that isn't JSON, it's *almost* JSON, but not JSON.  Many things break without proper JSON formatting...`JSON.parse()` on the browser for example.  You need to create valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks, but, as I stated in the first sentence above, I don't have any control over what gets sent to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't have any control over what gets sent to you, you are going to create your own custom parsing engine, as no JSON parsing will work reliably with what you are receiving.

Maybe you could cleanse/format the string that you receive INTO a JSON string and then parse it as JSON, but otherwise you have to write your own parsing implementation.

This part will not be over quickly. You will not enjoy it. I am not your king.

Comment: Do you know of any tools or libraries that can cleanse a JSON string?

Comment: Sorry, no... You may be on your own on this one :\

Comment: i saw that you accepted this answer. maybe if you look into http://jsonlint.com/ that could help you, but only for educational purposes. you can't wire anything up to that service, i don't believe